# Handling two forms from a single jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jsp

I have 2 forms in my jsp. The first form is a regular form which contains the user information. The second form is to submit the data to a third party api using its https url.

1st Form:

```
<form action"\doProcess">
     <input type="text" id="email" value=""/>
      other user details and inputs
</form>
```

2nd Form:

```
<form action="https://thirdpartyapi.com/do">
   //email from first form
     email to submit
</form>
```

So the email value must be from the first form email input value. I have tried to complete this using ajax instead of using the second form but there are cross domain policy restrictions which made me to come back to use two different forms. So here both forms must be submitted one after the other. Can any one please let me know how can i do this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what is `\doProces` doing

Comment: @brk that will just update the new user values in the database